How to tell file geodatabase' version using open source tools?
I have several  *.gdb folders that I like to tell the version of (for interoperability reasons). How can I do this using open source software? I'm familiar with QGIS and GDAL but still haven't found a way to to this.

There hasn't been a change in the file geodatabase version since ArcGIS 10.0.  Are you working with pre-10.0 file geodatabases?

Just to add to @bixb0012 comment...  ESRI says, at https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/client-geodatabase-compatibility.htm , that "The version for file geodatabases has not changed since 10.1."  See also:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/manage-file-gdb/upgrade-a-file-geodatabase.htm (not open source, but just for further info around fGDB versions).

Thanks. Though still a little bit unclear for me, that is what stated. Having said that, there were changes made to FGDB format since 10.1 (attribute rules; milliseconds; etc.). Furthermore, in ArcGIS Pro 3.2, one can create a schema report with a Geodatabase release return of 3.0 (this confuses me even more - what is the difference between the two?).

I found that I can drag and drop FGDB into QGIS and choose to add its system tables. The GDB_Items table contains an entry for the workspace and has xml definition value that contains the schema version. For a file geodatabase that was created in ArcGIS Pro 3.2, I'm getting a 10.8 version (in conjunction with the documentation regarding 10.1 ).

It is getting more difficult to find live/current Esri documentation that speaks to the early years of the geodatabase schema; however, I did manage to find one web page that sums it up fairly well:  Example: Finding the geodatabase release using SQL- ArcMap | Documentation.

Release numbers are stored as major, minor, and bug fix versions. In
XML, the major version is a numeric code that corresponds to the major
release of the geodatabase. ArcGIS 8 was the first release to include
ArcGIS geodatabase functionality; therefore, ArcGIS 8 corresponds to
major version 1. ArcGIS 9 corresponds to major version 2, and ArcGIS
10 corresponds to major version 3.

As several have pointed out in comments, there hasn't been a major change to the geodatabase structure since ArcGIS 10.0 was released in 2010.  What do I mean by "major change?" A change that would cause forward/backward compatibility or interoperability issues at the geodatabase level.  It is important to differentiate the compatibility and interoperability of geodatabase objects (feature classes, tables, etc...) from the compatibility and interoperability of the geodatabase itself.
Since I hope no one is running 15+ year-old software to do GIS today, I don't believe the motivation for this question is being represented by the question itself.
The Simplified Geodatabase Schema in ArcGIS 10 | ArcGIS Blog that Esri introduced almost 15 years ago didn't just simplify the geodatabase schema, it made it much more extensible and allows for geodatabase objects to add functionality over time without the geodatabase schema having to change itself, and therein lies the confusion when people go looking at the geodatabase schema version to infer compatibility or interoperability.
In a previous answer to this question, and in other GIS SE posts (arcgis desktop - Determining Personal Geodatabase version? - GIS SE), people have focused on the workspace schema version since the geodatabase schema versioning has caused confusion.  The problem with this approach is that compatibility and interoperability is an object-level issue and not a workspace-level issue.  An example of this can be seen by creating a new file geodatabase with ArcGIS Pro 3.2 and populating it with a range of tables that depend on newer functionality.
from arcpy.management import (
    CreateFileGDB,
    CreateTable,
    AddFields,
    AddGlobalIDs,
    AddAttributeRule
)

folder = r"C:\temp" # path to folder for creating file geodatabase
tables = {
    "OID32": {
        "path": None,
        "out_name": "OID32_table",
        "oid_type": "32_BIT",
        "field_description": "INT_FLD LONG"
    },
    "OID64": {
        "path": None,
        "out_name": "OID64_table",
        "oid_type": "64_BIT",
        "field_description": "INT_FLD LONG"
    },
    "DATE": {
        "path": None,
        "out_name": "date_table",
        "oid_type": "32_BIT",
        "field_description": "DATE_FLD DATE"
    },
    "DATEONLY": {
        "path": None,
        "out_name": "dateonly_table",
        "oid_type": "32_BIT",
        "field_description": "DATEONLY_FLD DATEONLY"
    },
    "ATTRRULES": {
        "path": None,
        "out_name": "attrrules_table",
        "oid_type": "32_BIT",
        "field_description": "INT_FLD LONG"
    }
}

fgdb = CreateFileGDB(folder, "fgdb")
for table in tables.values():
    table["path"] = CreateTable(fgdb, table["out_name"], oid_type=table["oid_type"])
    AddFields(table["path"], table["field_description"])

AddGlobalIDs(tables["ATTRRULES"]["path"])
AddAttributeRule(
    tables["ATTRRULES"]["path"],
    "constraintRuleIF",
    "CONSTRAINT",
    "$feature.INT_FLD > 5",
    "EDITABLE",
    "INSERT;UPDATE",
    "1",
    "INT_FLD not greater than 5"
)

The fgdb.gdb from the code above has a Workspace schema version of ArcGIS 10.8, but what exactly does that mean?  Does it mean only ArcGIS 10.8 and newer versions of software can open the file geodatabase and interact with the tables?  Does it mean ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1 can open the file geodatabase and interact with the all the tables?  The answer to both questions is, no, so what is the value of looking at the workspace schema version?
Since compatibility and interoperability are a feature class and table matter, and not a geodatabase schema matter, it is best to look at each feature class and table to determine its specific compatibility and interoperability.  Fortunately, Esri has a very specific and accurate DEFeatureClassInfo and DETableInfo element that tells us:  RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion.
Using ogrinfo to query the GDB_Items table of fgdb.gdb for RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion:
C:\>ogrinfo "C:\temp\fgdb.gdb" -dialect SQLITE -sql "SELECT name, substr(definition, instr(definition,'<RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion>')+34,4) RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion FROM GDB_Items WHERE definition LIKE '<DETableInfo%'"
INFO: Open of `C:\temp\fgdb.gdb'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 5
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Name: String (0.0)
RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  Name (String) = OID32_table
  RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion (String) = 10.0

OGRFeature(SELECT):1
  Name (String) = OID64_table
  RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion (String) = 13.2

OGRFeature(SELECT):2
  Name (String) = date_table
  RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion (String) = 10.0

OGRFeature(SELECT):3
  Name (String) = dateonly_table
  RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion (String) = 13.2

OGRFeature(SELECT):4
  Name (String) = attrrules_table
  RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion (String) = 12.1

The numbering seems odd since there is no ArcGIS 13.2, but how Esri has handled numbering for ArcGIS Pro is to add the version of Pro to "10.0," so a RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion of 13.2 means ArcGIS Pro 3.2 and RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion  of 12.1 means ArcGIS Pro 2.1.
Looking at the RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion value for the tables in fgdb.gdb, one can see that some of the tables would theoretically be compatible with ArcGIS 10.0 while one with attribute rules requires at least ArcGIS Pro 2.1, and one with a DATEONLY field requires ArcGIS Pro 3.2.

I found two ways to retrieve a File Geodatabase version using open source tools. Both relies on GDAL's ESRI File Geodatabase vector (OpenFileGDB) driver (bare in mind that this driver can read 9.X and 10.X FGDB version's; I'm yet to fully understand the 10.X version numbering and development system, but this to be addressed in a different thread):
QGIS (GUI way)

Drag'n'drop a non-zipped FGDB folder into an open instance of QGIS.
In the Select Items to Add window, check the Show system and internal tables checkbox, choose the GDB_Items layer\table and then Add Layers:

Open GDB_Items attribute table.
In the entry for which the name field value equals to Workspace, the Definition field will contain a XML string with the FGDB schema version appended to this url http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/[version]. e.g. http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.8:


GDAL (CLI way)
*Open OSGeo4W if you're using Windows OS.

Run the following command:

ogrinfo "[fgdb_path]" -q  -dialect SQLITE -sql "select substr(definition,instr(definition,'http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/')+35 ,4) fgdb_schema_version from GDB_Items where physicalname = 'WORKSPACE'"
e.g.
ogrinfo "C:\my_fgdb.gdb" -q  -dialect SQLITE -sql "select substr(definition,instr(definition,'http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/')+35 ,4) fgdb_schema_version from GDB_Items where physicalname = 'WORKSPACE'"

This will return the following text which includes the FGDB's schema version (I couldn't figure out how to retrieve only this line...):


Layer name: SELECT
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
fgdb_schema_version (String) = [vesrion]

e.g.

Layer name: SELECT
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
fgdb_schema_version (String) = 10.8


I would appreciate if someone with a known 9.X version FGDB, to try retrieving its version using one of the methods mentioned in the answer. This will help assure that these methods also apply to 9.X versions.

Prior to the 3.0 version of the geodatabase model, there was no gdb_items system table so neither of these work for file geodatabases created using ArcGIS 9.x.  That said, the lack of such a system table at least answers whether the FGDB was created with 9.x or 10.x version of ArcGIS.  See The Simplified Geodatabase Schema in ArcGIS 10 | ArcGIS Blog.  That same simplified geodatabase schema from ArcGIS 10 is still the current schema today.
